# print separately start and end date selected from daterangepicker method in android and print these in the form of date format

Tags: android, daterangepicker

daterangepicker in android helps us to select a range of dates and i want to show start date and end date of this range separately in different textviews.I don't know how to do it.
private Button bt1;
private TextView tv1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    bt1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
    final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();
    
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"date picker");
        }
    });

    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
           tv1.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: share your code, Thanks

Comment: please check now

Comment: Change `onPositiveButtonClick` selection param. type from `Object` to `Pair<Long, Long> ` and you can get range from it: `startDate = selection.first` `endDate = selection.second`

Comment: @AkakiKapanadze and what i should do if i want to print these dates?because using System.out.println(startDate);
                System.out.println(endDate); gives me this output : 1595203200000
    1596153600000 and i want date as output

Comment: @priks Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) for timestamp to human-readable date conversion

Comment: materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Pair<Long, Long>>() {
  @Override public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long,Long> selection) {
       Long startDate = selection.first;
       Long endDate = selection.second;
       //set text here of tv1 and tv2
  }
});